# What addon is this that adds an overlay showing number of admins online?

Tags: garrys-mod, game-identification, trouble-in-terrorist-town

What is this addon that basically shows the number of Admins online on the [Trouble in Terrorist Town](http://www.troubleinterroristtown.com/) server?

[image: Cropped screenshot showing the overlay created by the addon]
<sup>*Click to view larger image*</sup>

Comment: +1 for freehand circle (*and* for asking an identification question [properly](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5083/4163) without needing guidance!)

Comment: i think its a self made since its not that hard to make.

Answer (score 1):

It was most likely self made, so if you want to create something like it, you can go through the [advanced tutorial](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Workshop_Addon_Creation) if you know how to make an addon already or the [beginner tutorial](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Beginner_Tutorial_Intro) if you are new to modding with Lua.